# Can functors or monads respectively be expressed solely with higher order functions?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads, functor, higher-order-functions

I'm attempting to implement functors in Javascript without using container types (`[]`/`{}`). Hence, I solely utilize pure higher order functions to construct them:

```js
const option = x => f => isAssigned(x) ? option(f(x)) : none;

const none = option(null);


const isAssigned = x => x !== null && x !== undefined;
const inc = x => x + 1;
const sqr = x => x * x;
const head = xs => xs[0]
const log = x => (console.log(x), x);


option(head([4])) (inc) (sqr) (log); // 25

option(head([])) (inc) (sqr) (log); // not executed
```

`option` takes a value and a pure function, lifts the function into its context, applies it to the value and returns the result in the same context. I guess it is a functor. However, it doesn't follow the functor prototcol in Javascript, that each functor must own a map function on its prototype.

`option` can apparently be extended to a monad-like type (at least it behaves like one in my example):

```js
const option = x => f => isAssigned(x) ? option(f(x)) : none;

const option_ = x => f => isAssigned(x) ? flatten(option(f(x))) : none;

const none = option(null);

const of = x => option(x); // return

const flatten = F => { // it gets a bit ugly here
  let y;

  F(z => (y = z, z));
  return y;
};

// auxiliary functions

const compn = (...fs) => x => fs.reduceRight((acc, f) => f(acc), x);

const getOrElse = x => F => {
  let y;

  F(z => (y = z, z));
  return isAssigned(y) ? y : x;
};

const isAssigned = x => x !== null && x !== undefined;
const log = prefix => x => (console.log(prefix, x), x);
const head = xs => xs[0];
const head_ = xs => option(xs[0]);
const sqr = x => x * x;

// some data

const xs = [5],
 ys = [];

// run

const w = option(xs) (head),
 x = option(ys) (head),
 y = option_(xs) (head_),
 z = option_(ys) (head_);

log("square head  of xs:") (compn(sqr, getOrElse(1)) (w)); // 25

log("square head  of ys:") (compn(sqr, getOrElse(0)) (x)); // 0

log("square head_ of xs:") (compn(sqr, getOrElse(0)) (y)); // 25

log("square head_ of ys:") (compn(sqr, getOrElse(0)) (z)); // 0
```

Provided `option` is actually a functor my question is: Is it possible to express every functor/monad solely with (pure) higher order functions, where the results of contextual (or effectful) computations are held in the call stack?

Comment: why do you want to do this ? if "haskell in the browser" is your goal there are other solutions

Comment: @ftor Do you mean something like [Church encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding)?

Comment: @phg the theoretical basis, thanks. So it is theoretically possible. I still wonder whether there are practical problems to implement them in Javascript. Up to now `option` has no (proto)type. How can I associate functions (like `of`) with the right monad? Moreover, `option` is only a union. There are no tags and no means to reflect which of the possible types the union has adopted.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I'd say Church encoding is certainly more elegant than dealing around with `isAssigned`, since there are not internal nulls. `none` would become `x => x`, and `const of = x => _ => x` (in effect, we represent everything with `getOrDefault`). The rest of the combinators can be free functions, or methods of a wrapper object, I'd say. Tags are explicitely avoided, since we express everything by closures.

Comment: I'm not really a JS guy, but I've once played around with monads in it [here](https://github.com/phipsgabler/operajonal/blob/f41bb77b727191f348baff80708be5eacb84c3c9/examples/stacks.js#L88). Maybe you can take inspiration from that.

Comment: @phg I will look at your repo and Church encoding more closely. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. Aside from a couple JS primitives (`*`, `+`, `Number`, and `String`) to demonstrate functionality, below you will only see:

1. variables
2. lambda abstractions
3. applications

```js
const identity = x => x
const fromNullable = x => x == null ? None : Option(x)

const Option = (value) => k => {
  const join = () => value
  const map = f => Option(f(value))
  const bind = f => f(value)
  const ap = m => optionMap(value)(m)
  const fold = f => f(value)
  return k (value, join, map, bind, ap, fold)
}

const None = () => k => {
  const join = identity
  const map = f => None()
  const bind = f => None()
  const ap = m => None()
  const fold = f => f(null)
  return k (null, join, map, bind, ap, fold)
}

const optionJoin = m => m((value, join, map, bind, ap, fold) => join())
const optionMap = f => m => m((value, join, map, bind, ap, fold) => map(f))
const optionBind = f => m => m((value, join, map, bind, ap, fold) => bind(f))
const optionAp = n => m => m((value, join, map, bind, ap, fold) => ap(n))
const optionFold = f => m => m((value, join, map, bind, ap, fold) => fold(f))

optionFold (console.log) (Option(5)) // 5
optionFold (console.log) (None()) // null

optionFold (console.log) (optionMap (x => x * 2) (Option(5))) // 10
optionFold (console.log) (optionMap (x => x * 2) (None()))// null

optionFold (console.log) (optionAp(Option(3)) (Option(x => x + 4))) // 7
optionFold (console.log) (optionAp(Option(3)) (None())) // null

optionFold (console.log) (optionBind(x => Option(x * x)) (Option(16))) // 256
optionFold (console.log) (optionBind(x => Option(x * x)) (None())) // null

optionFold (console.log) (optionJoin (Option(Option('hi')))) // 'hi'
optionFold (console.log) (optionJoin (Option(None())))// null
```

We can skip some intermediate assignments and write it using only single-param lambdas -

```js
const Option = value => k => // unit
  k (_ => value)             // join
    (f => Option(f(value)))  // map
    (f => f(value))          // bind
    (m => map(value)(m))     // ap
    (f => f(value))          // fold

const None = k =>            // unit
  k (_ => None)              // join
    (_ => None)              // map
    (_ => None)              // bind
    (_ => None)              // ap
    (f => f(null))           // fold

const join = m =>
  m(v => _ => _ => _ => _ => v())
const map = f => m =>
  m(_ => v => _ => _ => _ => v(f))
const bind = f => m =>
  m(_ => _ => v => _ => _ => v(f))
const ap = f => m =>
  f(_ => _ => _ => v => _ => v(m))
const fold = f => m =>
  m(_ => _ => _ => _ => v => v(f))

const log =
  fold(console.log)

log(Option(5)) // 5
log(None)      // null

log(map (x => x * 2)(Option(5))) // 10
log(map (x => x * 2)(None))      // null

log(ap(Option(x => x + 4))(Option(3))) // 7
log(ap(Option(x => x + 4))(None))      // null
log(ap(None)(Option(3)))               // null

log(bind(x => Option(x * x))(Option(16))) // 256
log(bind(x => Option(x * x))(None))       // null

log(join(Option(Option('hi')))) // 'hi'
log(join(Option(None)))         // null
```

---

Maybe this help us see the pattern `m(_ => _ => ... => ?)` in the `join`, `map`, `bind`, `ap`, `fold` functions -

```js
const join = m =>
  m(v => _ => _ => _ => _ => v())
const map = f => m =>
  m(_ => v => _ => _ => _ => v(f))
const bind = f => m =>
  m(_ => _ => v => _ => _ => v(f))
const ap = f => m =>
  f(_ => _ => _ => v => _ => v(m))
const fold = f => m =>
  m(_ => _ => _ => _ => v => v(f))
```

This can be abstracted as a generic function. `arity(len)` returns a function, `arg(n)`, that returns a curried function with `len` parameters, that returns the `n`th argument. This is more plainly demonstrated in code -

```js
arity(3)(0)
// (x => _ => _ => x)

arity(4)(0)
// (x => _ => _ => _ => x)

arity(4)(1)
// (_ => x => _ => _ => x)

arity(4)(2)
// (_ => _ => x => _ => x)

arity(5)(3)
// (_ => _ => _ => x => _ => x)
```

We can implement `arity` like so -

```js
const arity = (len = 1) => (n = 0) =>
  len <= 1
    ? id
    : n <= 0
      ? comp(T)(arity(len - 1)(0))
      : T(arity(len - 1)(n - 1))

const id = x => x     // identity
const T = x => _ => x // true
const F = _ => x => x // false
const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x)) // function composition
```

Now we can easily write the public api functions as simple argument selectors -

```js
const Option = value => k => // unit
  k (value)                  // join
    (f => Option(f(value)))  // map
    (f => f(value))          // bind
    (m => map(m)(value))     // ap
    (f => f(value))          // fold

const None = k =>            // unit
  k (None)                   // join
    (_ => None)              // map
    (_ => None)              // bind
    (_ => None)              // ap
    (f => f(null))           // fold

const arg = arity(5)

const join = m => m(arg(0))
const map = m => m(arg(1))
const bind = m => m(arg(2))
const ap = m => m(arg(3))
const fold = m => m(arg(4))
```

There's nothing more to it :D Expand the snippet below to see verify the results in your own browser -

```js
const id = x => x     // identity
const T = x => _ => x // true
const F = _ => x => x // false
const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x)) // function composition

const arity = (len = 1) => (n = 0) =>
  len <= 1
    ? id
: n <= 0
    ? comp(T)(arity(len - 1)(0))
: T(arity(len - 1)(n - 1))

const arg = arity(5)

const Option = value => k => // unit
  k (value)                  // join
    (f => Option(f(value)))  // map
    (f => f(value))          // bind
    (m => map(m)(value))     // ap
    (f => f(value))          // fold

const None = k =>            // unit
  k (None)                   // join
    (_ => None)              // map
    (_ => None)              // bind
    (_ => None)              // ap
    (f => f(null))           // fold
    
const join = m => m(arg(0))
const map = m => m(arg(1))
const bind = m => m(arg(2))
const ap = m => m(arg(3))
const fold = m => m(arg(4))

const log = x =>
  fold(x)(console.log)

log(Option(5)) // 5
log(None)      // null

log(map(Option(5))(x => x * 2)) // 10
log(map(None)(x => x * 2))      // null

log(ap(Option(x => x + 4))(Option(3))) // 7
log(ap(Option(x => x + 4))(None))      // null
log(ap(None)(Option(3)))               // null

log(bind(Option(16))(x => Option(x * x))) // 256
log(bind(None)(x => Option(x * x)))       // null

log(join(Option(Option('hi')))) // 'hi'
log(join(Option(None)))         // null
```

Comment: You put the whole API into the `Option` type. That makes sense. I will play around with it a bit and come back to you later.

Comment: yeah treating it sort of like a type class – conveniently tho, both Option and None type can define their own "methods"

Comment: That's it. Good work, thank you! We can even offer a convenience function `const optionMap_ = m => f => optionMap_(m((value, join, map, bind, ap, fold) => map(f)))` so that something like `optionMap_(Option(5)) (inc) (sqr) (log)` is possible.

Comment: Nit-picking: Maybe you can add `return` (`of` in fantasy land) and a `none` value, so that the additional function calls can be avoided.

Comment: Agreed. It was mostly proof of concept to show it's possible using only functions. We could always implement a record type using functions then user that to build our functors and monads, too. Fun exercise ^_^

Comment: You mean a record type to structure the API for improved access? This can't be particularly difficult. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Yeah. Also the way they're currently defined, the types are "closed" — ie, we couldn't easily add a "method" (eg `of`) somewhere else in the code, if at all.